# JSSOR carousel slider not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, slider, jssor

```js
var BulletNavOptions = { $Class: SliderOpt.BulletNavigatorOptions.Class, $ChanceToShow: 1, $AutoCenter: 1, $Steps: 1, $Lanes: 3, $SpacingX: 10, $SpacingY: 5, $Orientation: 1 };
  
var ArrowNavOptions = { $Class: SliderOpt.ArrowNavigatorOptions.Class, $ChanceToShow: 1, $AutoCenter: 0, $Steps: 1 };
  
var options = { $AutoPlay: true, $AutoPlaySteps: 1, $AutoPlayInterval: 3000, $FillMode:0, $DisplayPieces: 3, $SlideWidth: 400, $SlideHeight: 300, $ArrowKeyNavigation: true, $SlideDuration: 200, $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 0, $SlideSpacing: 10, $ParkingPosition: 0, $PauseOnHover: 3, $PlayOrientation: 1, $DragOrientation: 1, $StartIndex: 0, $Loop: 1, $LazyLoading: 1, $BulletNavigatorOptions: BulletNavOptions, $ArrowNavigatorOptions: ArrowNavOptions};

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(_container, options);
```

```html
<DIV id=span_mlgrid class=x-form-con-grid style="OVERFLOW: hidden; HEIGHT: 300px; WIDTH: 1210px; POSITION: relative" jssor-slider="true">
<DIV style="OVERFLOW: hidden; HEIGHT: 300px; WIDTH: 1210px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px" u="slides">
<DIV><IMG src="../Resources/chrysalis/images/PlfControlLibrary/Default/001.jpg" width=720 height=480 u="image"></DIV>
<DIV><IMG src="../Resources/chrysalis/images/PlfControlLibrary/Default/002.jpg" width=720 height=480 u="image"></DIV>
<DIV><IMG src="../Resources/chrysalis/images/PlfControlLibrary/Default/003.jpg" width=720 height=480 u="image"></DIV>
<DIV><IMG src="../Resources/chrysalis/images/PlfControlLibrary/Default/004.jpg" width=720 height=480 u="image"></DIV></DIV>
<STYLE type=text/css>.jssorb03 DIV {
 OVERFLOW: hidden; CURSOR: pointer; BACKGROUND: url(../Resources/chrysalis/images/PlfControlLibrary/b05.png) no-repeat
}
.jssorb03 DIV:hover {
 OVERFLOW: hidden; CURSOR: pointer; BACKGROUND: url(../Resources/chrysalis/images/PlfControlLibrary/b05.png) no-repeat
}
.jssorb03 .av {
 OVERFLOW: hidden; CURSOR: pointer; BACKGROUND: url(../Resources/chrysalis/images/PlfControlLibrary/b05.png) no-repeat
}
.jssorb03 DIV {
 BACKGROUND-POSITION: -5px -4px
}
.jssorb03 DIV:hover {
 BACKGROUND-POSITION: -35px -4px
}
.jssorb03 .av:hover {
 BACKGROUND-POSITION: -35px -4px
}
.jssorb03 .av {
 BACKGROUND-POSITION: -65px -4px
}
.jssorb03 .dn {
 BACKGROUND-POSITION: -95px -4px
}
.jssorb03 .dn:hover {
 BACKGROUND-POSITION: -95px -4px
}
</STYLE>

<DIV style="RIGHT: 6px; POSITION: absolute; BOTTOM: 15px" u="navigator" class="jssorb03">
<DIV style="FONT-SIZE: 12px; HEIGHT: 21px; WIDTH: 21px; POSITION: absolute; COLOR: white; TEXT-ALIGN: center; LINE-HEIGHT: 21px" u="prototype"></DIV></DIV>
<STYLE type=text/css>.jssora03l {
 OVERFLOW: hidden; CURSOR: pointer; BACKGROUND: url(../Resources/chrysalis/images/PlfControlLibrary/a03.png) no-repeat; POSITION: absolute; DISPLAY: block
}
.jssora03r {
 OVERFLOW: hidden; CURSOR: pointer; BACKGROUND: url(../Resources/chrysalis/images/PlfControlLibrary/a03.png) no-repeat; POSITION: absolute; DISPLAY: block
}
.jssora03ldn {
 OVERFLOW: hidden; CURSOR: pointer; BACKGROUND: url(../Resources/chrysalis/images/PlfControlLibrary/a03.png) no-repeat; POSITION: absolute; DISPLAY: block
}
.jssora03rdn {
 OVERFLOW: hidden; CURSOR: pointer; BACKGROUND: url(../Resources/chrysalis/images/PlfControlLibrary/a03.png) no-repeat; POSITION: absolute; DISPLAY: block
}
.jssora03l {
 BACKGROUND-POSITION: -3px -33px
}
.jssora03r {
 BACKGROUND-POSITION: -63px -33px
}
.jssora03l:hover {
 BACKGROUND-POSITION: -123px -33px
}
.jssora03r:hover {
 BACKGROUND-POSITION: -183px -33px
}
.jssora03ldn {
 BACKGROUND-POSITION: -243px -33px
}
.jssora03rdn {
 BACKGROUND-POSITION: -303px -33px
}
</STYLE>
<SPAN style="HEIGHT: 55px; WIDTH: 55px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 8px; TOP: 40%" u="arrowleft" class="jssora03l"></SPAN><SPAN style="HEIGHT: 55px; WIDTH: 55px; RIGHT: 8px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 40%" u="arrowright" class="jssora03r"></SPAN></DIV>
```

I have dynamically created jssor carousel slider which works perfectly in chrome and firefox but not in IE.

The following condition, for slides container though overflow:hidden is specified, is failing only in IE,
`***jssor.slider.js:2812***
if (slidesContainerOverflow != "hidden" && (slidesContainerOverflowX != "hidden" || slidesContainerOverflowY != "hidden"))
                $JssorDebug$.$Fail("Overflow of slides container wrong specification, it should be specified as 'hidden' (style='overflow:hidden;').");`

Code snippet for Slides creation:

```
divSlides = document.createElement("div");        
            divSlides.setAttribute("u","slides");
            var slidestyle = "position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px;";      
            divSlides.setAttribute("style",slidestyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
divSlides.setAttribute("style",slidestyle);
```

with

```
divSlides.style.cssText = slidestyle;
```

If there is still problem, please post generated html code here.

Comment: I have replaced the code as suggested and now the validation gone through for slides but the same issue has occured for BulletNavigator (`jssor.slider.js:3325`) and ArrowNavigator (`jssor.slider.js:3363`).  

After replacing the navigator styles too with this suggested code the slider rendered with out any errors but the navigators are not visible. 

The navigators are generated with `Display:none` in style definition. The generated html code has been posted here with.

Comment: I had a look to the code, it is not the raw code you generated.

Comment: I mean the code you generated (created) dynamically.

Comment: I have posted the generated html content and options specified to  initialize the slider.

Comment: I noticed width and height of 'slides' container are not specified.

Comment: The width and height for slides container has been specified. `<DIV id=span_mlgrid class=x-form-con-grid style="OVERFLOW: hidden; HEIGHT: 300px; WIDTH: 1210px; POSITION: relative" jssor-slider="true">
<DIV style="OVERFLOW: hidden; HEIGHT: 300px; WIDTH: 1210px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px" u="slides">`

Comment: btw, you don't need to generate navigator css dynamically, it can be moved out.

Comment: Yep, it works when the generated code is tested separately but when i integrate it with my application the navigators are not visible though i couldnt find any difference in the generated code as well as in the rendered html code. can you have a look at it?

Comment: Any url that I can have a look?

Comment: url is not exposed, please use this url (valid for 20 mins) to connect to my desktop [link](https://broker.gotoassist.com/h/ramco?Question=DR276-373-528)

Comment: It seems to be a download link.

Comment: url has timed out. please connect using [link](https://broker.gotoassist.com/h/ramco?Question=DR648-012-616)

Comment: I can't access your page, a java plugin is required.

Comment: again, please use `divSlides.style.cssText = slidestyle;` instead.

Comment: I have used the above syntax to set the style for slides, bullet and arrow but still the issue persists only when i integrate this to my application whereas it works perfectly as a standalone html page. And this issue occurs only in IE.

Comment: It would be great if you have a look on the app. Can you connect thru the url once again?

Comment: Still `java(TM) is required`.

Comment: I received your email, please let me know how you call `CreateImageSlider`.